# Page break on print issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem on print,
The data is scrolling horizontally, (which results in cutting the content on print).

i.e

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I want to break the page, after 5 elements, which is overflowing horizontally..
like

0 1 2 3 4

0 1 2 3 4

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

5 6 7 8 9

5 6 7 8 9

but my idea will result will difinitely be,

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

Any Idea...?

because the content is dynamic and vary with the situation, so i can't start untill have a clear idea,

Comment: give some fiddle man or else give some left-right padding to its parent with word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;

Comment: Can you provide some sample code (preferably in the form of a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) so we can get a better idea of the context of what you're talking about? Also, is this Java or JavaScript? Java is not JavaScript, nor are the two even particularly closely related.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bzKsY/

Comment: tag is JavaScript actually, mistakenly selected java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Men I have the soluttion...

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script>

//method
    var table="<datalist><p>";
    var lines=3;//number of lines you want
            var i = 0,aux=lines;
            lines=lines*2;
            do {
                if(lines>aux){table=table+"<span>"+i+"</span>";if(i==4){lines--;table=table+"</p><p>";}if(lines>aux && i==4){i=-1;}}
                i++;
                if(lines!=0 && lines<=aux){table=table+"<span>"+i+"</span>";if(i==9){lines--;i=4;table=table+"</p><p>";}}
            } while (lines>0);
            table=table+"</datalist>";
//method

//here print table
             document.writeln(table);
            </script>

            <style>
                datalist {
                    font-size:14px; overflow: auto;display:block;
                 }
                datalist span{ 
                    padding:2px 5px; border:1px solid #000;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>   
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know in what lenguage you want the code, and what varibles are using, but it's a way in `java`:

```
int lines=3;
        int i = 0,aux=lines;
        lines=lines*2;
        do {
            if(lines>aux){System.out.print(i);if(i==4){lines--;System.out.println("");}if(lines>aux && i==4){i=-1;}}
            i++;
            if(lines!=0 && lines<=aux){System.out.print(i);if(i==9){lines--;i=4;System.out.println("");}}
        } while (lines>0);
```

change the `int lines` to change the **number of double lines you want**
in HTML the only way is using JavaScript,

I hope this can help you!